# Finding what a span class is equal too with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the Code I currently have

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Airtable API credentials and identifiers
AIRTABLE_API_KEY = 'deletedForPrivacy'
AIRTABLE_BASE_ID = 'deletedForPrivacy'
AIRTABLE_TABLE_NAME = 'deletedForPrivacy'

# Airtable API endpoint
AIRTABLE_ENDPOINT = f'https://api.airtable.com/v0/{AIRTABLE_BASE_ID}/{AIRTABLE_TABLE_NAME}'

# Headers for Airtable API
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {AIRTABLE_API_KEY}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}


# Function to get records from Airtable
def get_airtable_records():
    response = requests.get(AIRTABLE_ENDPOINT, headers=headers)
    return response.json()


# Function to check the booking admin page for the "Approved" status
def check_booking_status(html_content):
    # Parse the HTML with BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

    # Search for the 'Approved' status tag
    status_tag = soup.find('span', class_='status_tag approved')
    print(status_tag)
    # Check if the 'Approved' status tag is found and return the result
    return 'Approved' if status_tag else 'Not Approved'


# Function to update the "Tags" field in Airtable
def update_airtable_record(record_id, tag):
    data = {
        'fields': {
            'Tags': tag
        }
    }
    response = requests.patch(f'{AIRTABLE_ENDPOINT}/{record_id}', headers=headers, json=data)
    return response.json()


# Main execution function
def main():
    records = get_airtable_records()
    for record in records.get('records', []):
        booking_link = record['fields'].get('Booking Admin Link')
        if booking_link:
            # Assuming booking_link is a URL to fetch the HTML content
            response = requests.get(booking_link)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                booking_status = check_booking_status(response.text)
                if booking_status == 'Approved':
                    update_airtable_record(record['id'], 'Approved')
                else:
                    update_airtable_record(record['id'], 'Pending')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This portion is what is not working

```
def check_booking_status(html_content):
# Parse the HTML with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

# Search for the 'Approved' status tag
status_tag = soup.find('span', class_='status_tag approved')
print(status_tag)
# Check if the 'Approved' status tag is found and return the result
return 'Approved' if status_tag else 'Not Approved'
```

And I am trying to pull this snippet from the url:

```
<div class="panel">
      <h3>Captain</h3>
      <div class="panel_contents">
        <b>
Status on booking          
<span class="status_tag approved">Approved</span>
        </b>
        <hr/>
```

There are two options it can be

```
<span class="status_tag approved"> Approved</span>
```

or it can be

```
<span class="status_tag pending"> Pending</span>
```

I need to know when it is approved and return as so. Currently when I run it with the print(status_tag) it just prints out none for every instance even though there are some in there that are approved

Comment: Are you sure it is in your `response`  maybe the content of website is rendered dynamically by JavaScript.

Comment: Right.  Do "View Source" in your browser -- that's what `requests.get` sees.  It doesn't see the tags in the DOM.  For that, you'd need to use something like Selenium.

Comment: When I do view source that HTML code pops up.